Why distant objects are becoming white when camera is still?

I have a shader attached to quads that I'm generating far away using
script. The quad is capable of keeping the color when camera is moving
however the color becomes white when camera is still. I can't guess
why it's happening or what is the reason for it to become white and what can I do about it?

When camera is moving:

When camera is not moving:


Did you happen to disable clearing the colour buffer? Or do you have any adaptive exposure / HDR settings set up on your camera? Try walking us through the complete steps we'd need to follow to reproduce this problem in a new, empty project. Once we can reproduce it, we can test potential fixes to be sure they'll solve it in your case.

@DMGregory I have tried to recreate the problem in an empty project and noticed that it only happens when the 10000 quads around camera has almost similar color (meaning the variation of color is limited to 3 or 4 mostly yellowish color). But this doesn't happen when the variation of color is large. Also I don't have any extra settings in my camera.

Sounds like you've isolated a repro case. Please edit your question to walk a reader through the complete steps to build this Minimal Complete Verifiable Example.
